# What signature can I use to download files using Axum and Tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I'm using axum and this code ([found here](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/discussions/608#discussioncomment-1789020)) to download files:

```rust
use axum::{
    body::StreamBody,
    http::{header, StatusCode},
    response::{Headers, IntoResponse},
    routing::get,
    Router,
};
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio_util::io::ReaderStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new().route("/", get(handler));

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));
    axum::Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn handler() -> impl IntoResponse {
    // `File` implements `AsyncRead`
    let file = match tokio::fs::File::open("Cargo.toml").await {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(err) => return Err((StatusCode::NOT_FOUND, format!("File not found: {}", err))),
    };

    // convert the `AsyncRead` into a `Stream`
    let stream = ReaderStream::new(file);

    // convert the `Stream` into an `axum::body::HttpBody`
    let body = StreamBody::new(stream);

    let headers = Headers([
        (header::CONTENT_TYPE, "text/toml; charset=utf-8"),
    ]);

    Ok((headers, body))
}
```

Everything works. But I cannot find a way to move the below code in a separate function:

```rust
let file = match tokio::fs::File::open("Cargo.toml").await {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(err) => return Err((StatusCode::NOT_FOUND, format!("File not found: {}", err))),
};
```

**I would like to use both `tokio::fs::File` and `https://crates.io/crates/rust-s3` methods in this function.**

So I need a "common type" which appear to be `AsyncRead`, I think.

What should be the signature of the function?

I tried with:

```rust
use tokio::io::AsyncRead;

pub struct Player {
    db: Arc<DB>
}

impl Handler {
    pub async fn player_pdf(
        &self,
        id: &str,
    ) -> Result<&(dyn AsyncRead)> {
        //...use id here...

        let file = &tokio::fs::File::open("player.pdf").await?;

        Ok(file)
    }
}
```

but I get the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    |
55  |         Ok(file)
    |         -- ^^^^
    |         |  |
    |         |  expected reference, found struct `tokio::fs::File`
    |         |  help: consider borrowing here: `&file`
    |         arguments to this enum variant are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected reference `&dyn tokio::io::AsyncRead`
                  found struct `tokio::fs::File`
```

I tried with: `let file = &tokio::fs::File::open("player.pdf").await?;` and I got:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
   |
43 |         let file = &tokio::fs::File::open(...
   |                     --------------------------- temporary value created here
...
55 |         Ok(file)
   |         ^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

What can I use?

Comment: You can't return a reference to a temporary like that. Why not just return a `Box<dyn AsyncRead>`? Then `Box::new(tokio::fs::File::open(...))`. There might be another way if you're prepared to nail down your return type to what Tokio gives you.

Comment: Sorry @tadman, I updated the question with: I would like to use both `tokio::fs::File` and `https://crates.io/crates/rust-s3` methods in this function.

So I need a "common type" which appear to be `AsyncRead`, I think.

Comment: This is the reason I have this issue.

Comment: You can use `Box` to wrap it up with `dyn` inside. The downside here is this is allocated dynamically, but if you're not doing this millions of times per process, the overhead is inconsequential.

Comment: What is another way avoiding Box?

Comment: Writing an `enum` which encapsulates your use cases and then implementing that trait all over again, which is really _not fun_. Not sure you should be really concerned with `Box` being in the middle. It's a common way to pass around a *thing that implements trait* in Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a generic "boxed" value might be the solution here:

```rust
impl Handler {
    pub async fn player_pdf(
        &self,
        id: &str,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn AsyncRead>> {
        //...use id here...

        Ok(Box::new(tokio::fs::File::open("player.pdf").await?))
    }
}
```

Where now there's no dangling reference, it's encapsulated and fully owned.

Comment: I tried your code but I get the error:

```log
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn tokio::io::AsyncRead` cannot be known at compilation time
    |
132 |     let stream = ReaderStream::new(*res);
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `dyn tokio::io::AsyncRead`
```

Comment: remove the `*` and make the return type `Box<dyn AsyncRead + Unpin>`

Comment: You could also skip the `AsyncRead` part and just return `Box<dyn Stream>`, doing the stream conversion inside this function, like you seem to want anyway.

Comment: I don't understand `doing the stream conversion inside this function, like you seem to want anyway`

Comment: It seems you immediately wrap the result of this inside `ReaderStream::file()` so you end up with that instead. If you're going to do that in all cases, might be more convenient if your function just returned (a boxed version of) that. Instead of forcing implementations to conform to `AsyncRead` you could relax a bit and expect the stream trait instead, which in the future might give you more latitude.

Comment: Do you mean `use futures::Stream`?

Comment: If I use `Box<dyn Stream>` it says: `error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Item` (from trait `futures::Stream`) must be specified`

Comment: And know I need to specify the type, right? Which Type? AsyncRead?

Comment: It's just an idea. I wouldn't fuss over it. I think [`ReaderStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/io/struct.ReaderStream.html) is a type, not a trait, which could eliminate the `Box` if you return that instead. `Result<ReaderStream>` means no more references, boxes, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. It works. But I'm forced to declare it with specific type, like this: `Result<ReaderStream<tokio::fs::File>>`. Is there another way?

Comment: Ah, that takes all the fun out of it, doesn't it? In that case, I guess you're stuck with boxes. No big deal, they're fine.

Comment: Yeah. Just one more thing: If I change the signature to `Result<Option<Pin<Box<dyn AsyncRead + Send>>>` it errors with: expected enum `std::option::Option<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn tokio::io::AsyncRead + std::marker::Send>>>`
               found enum `std::option::Option<std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<tokio::fs::File>>>` Why?

Comment: I'm using `let res = Some(Box::pin(file));` of course. If I remove the `Option<>` it works!

Comment: Not sure if you need to pin the option, or option the pin. Never used it like that before.

Comment: With or without Pin.

Comment: expected enum `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<dyn tokio::io::AsyncRead + std::marker::Send>>`
               found enum `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<tokio::fs::File>>`

Comment: At this point you may want to open up a new question to focus on that intermediate approach.

Comment: Using: `let file = tokio::fs::File::open("player.pdf").await?; let res = Some(Box::new(file));`

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778822/why-this-function-works-without-option-and-doesnt-with-it